# Permutation: How many ways to put 7 people in 10 rooms?

Tags: permutations

> How many ways can 7 people be placed into 10 rooms, if (only) 2 of them can’t share a room with anyone?

I'm not sure how to go about this, mostly because of the "share a room" bit. I'm thinking I should calculate the number of ways 2 people can be placed into 10 rooms, then the number of ways the remaining 5 people can be placed into the 8 rooms left, and multiply the two figures together. Am I on the right track?

Also, does sharing rooms mean "with replacement"?

Comment: Are there two particular people that won't share?  If so, then your approach is right.  Figure out how many ways you can place those two in $10$ rooms.  Then figure out how many ways you can place the other five in $8$ rooms, and then multiply.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, you were on the right track. There are $\binom{10}2$ choices for the two rooms for the hermites, and then $8^5$ ways to select one of the remaining $8$ rooms for each of the remaining $5$ people, for a total of $\binom{10}2\cdot8^5=1474560$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $10\cdot9$ instead of $10\choose2$?

Comment: I'm a newb so I could be totally off but I also think it should be $10*9$. Because by doing (10 choose 2) you are not distinguishing between the selections of the two loners. For example the first loner choosing room 1 and second loner choosing room 2 is the same as the first loner choosing room 2 and the second loner choosing room 1. This should count as 2 different configurations, however by doing (10 choose 2) it would count as 1... please correct me if I'm wrong.